# Using a select menu to remove and add options with AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html-select

With the help of a stack, I created a form which has two select menus (A + B). Based on options in Menu A -> options in menu B are added in between specific existing options. For this, I am using the following $ ajax function like so

```
function fetch_new_options(val) {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'fetch_new_options.php',
        data: {
            get_selected_option_id: val
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            elemToReplaceBefore = $("#select_values option[value = '--']");
            $(response).insertBefore(elemToReplace);
            //                        elemToReplaceBefore.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

It almost works, the problem is every new options is added and not replaced.

```
Menu B
Option B1
Option B2
-----
Option Bxx
Option Bxx
```

But when I change Menu A and say the new options are D1, D2 and D3 it becomes

```
Menu B
Option B1
Option B2
New option C1
New option C2
New option D1
New option D2
New option D3
Option Bxx
Option Bxx
```

and not

```
Menu B
Option B1
Option B2
New option D1
New option D2
New option D3
Option Bxx
Option Bxx
```

How can I replace the new options and not just add? Does a `.insertReplace` exist?

Should I add a class to the menu B option elements and use `.replaceWith`?

Comment: There are any number of tutorials and SO questions that describe the entire process.

Comment: so you intend to replace but it is getting appended...am i correct ?

Comment: what is the unique ID about the option you are trying to replace ??? or just no ID

Comment: Sorry I edit my question to 'hopefully' make it a bit clearer

Comment: can you try using `console.log(response)` and print the options that are received after the response,  are they returning correct options?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yes all returning options are correct (from a db) Only thing i need is to replace them. In the .php file I echo the new options. I now have added a class so <option class="tr_new_option"> and try to remove the options with this class before triggering the .php again. No luck so far

Comment: that is strange can you add a working code snippet to your problem we can go through it and find what is wrong.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam i think i found a solution by removing the options on document ready ` $(document).ready(function () {
                console.log("ready!");
                // Trigger T&R
                $('#menuA').change(function () {
                    $(".tr_new_option").remove(); ,<--
selectId = $('#menuA').val();
if (selectId != "") {
                        fetch_new_options(selectId);
                    }`

Comment: glad if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

you must use the `$("#select_value option[value='foo']").remove();` to remove the specific option you want to be removed, like you have in the code `elemToReplaceBefore.remove()` , but this will always remove the first options with the `value='--'` if you want to remove all values that existed before sending the ajax call `$('#select_values').empty()`

Comment: @muhammed, but when I remove I don't have a selector to insertBefore or after?
Btw: I edit my question a bit